# Unexpected return code while testing spring controller

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin, testing

I have simple RestController in my application, with post mapping

```
@PostMapping("/bank/api/balance")
    fun changeBalance(@RequestParam amount: String, @RequestParam action: String)
```

And I have test function for this controller.

```
private fun postBalanceAddRequest(amount: String): ResultActions {
        return mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(baseUrl).apply {
            param("action", "add")
            param("amount", amount)
        })
    }
```

Which I am using in this test

```
@Test
        fun `add post request must return ok if request contains correct data`() {
            Mockito.`when`(authenticationService.getCurrentUserUsername()).thenReturn("user")
            Mockito.`when`(userService.userExist("user")).thenReturn(true)

            postBalanceAddRequest(amount = "10")
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)

        }
```

When I start this test I got 404 code, but it seems to me that there cannot be such a return code here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this
`private val baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/bank/api/balance"`

Answer (score 1):

when using `MockMvc` you don't need to provide the full url (including domain and port), the mockMvc will take care of it.
instead, you need just the uri. set your `baseUrl` to `/bank/api/balance`

Comment: But I use full url in same case, and it works. Anyway, I try to use your advice and get 404

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, I just forgot to add a necessary controller. As for mockMvc, you can use short url, without domain and port
(I think it is the best way), but if you want you can use full url.

Comment: Please can you share more details if your are posting as an answer. This will help others in future!